# Why does this arithmetic expression produce this result?

Tags: c

Can some one explain to me the out put of this simple code segment?

```
int i=7;
int j=3*i-- + 2;
printf("%d %d",i,j)
```

When I compile I get `6,23`.

How does it come to 23? I thought it would be 3*7=21 decrease to 20 and added 2 is 22 not 23?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i = 7; /* i is 7 */
int j = (3 * (i--)) /* means 3 * 7 */ + 2; /* 3 * 7 + 2 = 23 */
/* i is now 6, because it was decreased by the postfix -- operator */
printf("%d %d", i /* 6 */, j /* 23 */);
```

Answer (score 2):

`i--` does have the side effect of decrementing `i` by 1 (setting it to 6), but the expression yields the *previous* value of `i`.  `--i` would decrement `i` and yield the *new* result.

Answer (score 1):

`--` binds to `i`, not to `3*i`. (You couldn't have `(3*i)--` in any case as `3*i` is not an lvalue which `--` requires.) The value of `i--` is the original value of `i` before it is decremented.

Answer (score 1):

List of unary operators in C: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation#C_family_of_languages

`--` is a unary operator and binds to `i`, so it's `i--`, not `(3 * i)--`.

Since it's post-decrement, the value of `i` BEFORE decrementing is used, so your equation is just:

`3 * 7 + 2`, and `i` will be 6.